# geometry nodes - doo sabin

Tags: geometry-nodes

Using geometry nodes - how to create doo sabin modifier:

[image]

1st image is original mesh
2nd image is desired result
3rd image is after 2nd iteration

"The Doo-Sabin process generates one new face at each original vertex, new faces along each original edge, and new faces at each original face."

Comment: If you want to do it non-destructively, use a _Bevel_ modifier for step 1. Set the _Segments_ to 1 and the _Limit Method_ to _None_. Step 2 is a bit problematic... the rounding of the shape could be accomplished with a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier, but it wouldn't make the yellow and blue parts narrower.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: Looks like Markus von Broady doesn't think it's problematic :D :D :D

Comment: @Chris coloring coming soon :)

Comment: @Chris Yeah, I didn't think about GN and actually never really thought about what _Dual Mesh_ is doing. While everyone else in tutorials etc. nowadays doesn't seem to do anything else than GN, I only have rudimentary knowledge of it and almost never use it in my daily tasks.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: Whaaaat?! I just made a tutorial about animation nodes!!! Which i think - is still much more powerful than geometry nodes (in a lot of areas) and you can make a lot more with it and its possibilities are far less restricted because - you can make your own nodes AND(!) you can use the whole Blender API via using python (python nodes!). And as I understood GN - python nodes will never come (although I don’t know why)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: I wouldn’t came up with such a solution as well even so I have a little GN experience…Marcus is - like just some others here - which aren’t many but some - from another „planet“ - he has an outstanding understanding of GN and other things - which I wish I had - but I am still learning…

Comment: @Chris I know Animation Nodes. But still very many new tutorials use Geometry Nodes. And for my daily work I need neither of them. Mostly just simple modelling and texturing. Oh, and I know answers from Markus. I've been on this site for a while now ;)

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if you want to achieve the coloring, without it the setup is pretty simple:

[image]

[image]

### Coloring

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: niiiiiiiiiiiice! +1

Comment: @Chris I lost over 2 hours because the statistics part of the node tree was failing, and I thought it's the logic in the "next iterations" and redone it like 5 times always with same results ARRRRGH

Comment: Great stuff.. I bet the OP colouring was only to illustrate....  XD

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady : don’t worry - i waste my time with much simpler stuff! ‍♂️

Comment: Wow! When I posted this I thought "This is a hard question"... this answer exceeded my expectations!!