# Can you implement these subd. algorithms while exposing their parameters using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, 3d-printing, mathematics

Using geometry nodes - How can we implement [Catmull-Clark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface) and [Doo-Sabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doo%E2%80%93Sabin_subdivision_surface) [Doo-Sabin](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/277019/35559) subd. algorithms while exposing their parameters using geometry nodes.

I've been looking for coding examples on Michael Hansmeyer "Subdivided Columns" or something like it.  I want to experiment and 3D print some small test models.

[image: img0]

[image: img1]

I can find data on simple fractals

[Getting the total length of all edges using geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/285783/getting-the-total-length-of-all-edges-using-geometry-nodes) and [Fractals in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/fractals-in-blender)

[image: img2]

But nothing on Michael Hansmeyer "Subdivided Columns" which was done in 2009-2010.  Any thoughts in recreating something like this?

**Background:**

His Ted talk https://www.ted.com/speakers/michael_hansmeyer

**A paper describing it.**

http://papers.cumincad.org/cgi-bin/works/paper/ecaade2010_192

**Website:**

https://www.michael-hansmeyer.com/subdivided-columns

**Update:** As mentioned by Robin Betts I'm trying to re-frame the question.

Comment: Since you've provided no information on who 'Michael Hansmeyer' is or any links to him, how are we expected to answer that question?

Comment: @JohnEason ok  I added a link to his Ted Talk along with his paper.

Comment: I don't know what you are expecting from us... should we now work our way through all the Ted talk and paper, find formulas for fractals and then figure out how to implement this in _Geometry Nodes_? Fractals are quite complex, you know - not trivial. This site is not for giving elaborate tutorials. Try this one by Bad Normals, here he is creating a fractal in GN: [Blender is getting CRAZY!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xuLIJ-FNkSI)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann JohnEason asked for it so I posted it.  I was just putting it out there.  I'm always overjoyed any of my "crazy" questions get answered or get a response no matter what it is.  It gives me different points of views I wouldn't have gotten otherwise.

Comment: For those not prepared to go through the refs, these objects seem to be  made by recursive subd, using atypical, and varying,  parameters to  [Catmull-Clark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface) and  [Doo-Sabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doo%E2%80%93Sabin_subdivision_surface) algorithms. Rick T .. maybe a better  question for BSE is: 'Can you implement these subd. algorithms, exposing their parameters?' I like the project, but think it has to be reframed to be answerable here, BTW, these objects are hopelessly pathologcal, from a 3D printing POV.

Comment: Personally, I  hate to lose this question, but I think it _has_ to be reframed for BSE. Try something like my suggestion above, so it's a definite question, susceptible to a definite set of answers. ( Like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/277019/35559), but you want to screw with the  lengths, etc. ) . You can still link to the refs to show your motives. At the moment, this Q would be fine on a chat-forum, but not in a Stack Exchange archive.

Comment: @RobinBetts I gave it a shot. It really comes from some emails / video from Dr Cohen he said you just have to try it.  "In general, the fractal parts produce 'fractal loading' and makes the antenna smaller for a given frequency of use. Practical shrinkage of 2-4 times are realizable for a given performance level. Multiband behavior is manifest at non-harmonic frequencies"  https://www.fractenna.com/our/antennatech.html .  He's 3D printing them now so I just wanted to try something like it but with a little twist.